# Vue Components style display differently on page than when not used as components

Tags: html, css, vue.js

I am working on moving chunks of code from being static code within my Views components into actual reusable Components.

I have moved what is called my TrainerCards code into a separate component and the cards used to display nicely as 3 to a row when they were hard coded in my TrainerIndex.vue, but now that they are being passed as a component, they only render as 1 per row, and I don't know why.
TrainerIndex.vue -

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <TrainerCards v-for="trainer in orderBy(filterBy(trainers, searchText), sortAttribute, sortAscending)" :key="trainer.id" :trainer="trainer"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

`
TrainerCards.vue -

```
<template>
  <div class="card card-profile">
    <div class="card-img-top">
        <router-link v-bind:to="'/trainers/' + trainer.id">
          <img class="img" :src="(trainer.avatar)" />
        </router-link>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <h4 class="card-title">{{trainer.full_name}}</h4>
      <h6 class="card-category">{{trainer.location}}</h6>
      <div class="card-footer">
        <TrainerTags v-for="tag in trainer.tags" :key="tag.id" :tag="tag"/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Any idea on how to get them to display properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `col-md-4` class is what makes them fill 1/3 of the area, but that is now outside your component and not repeating.  Move that div inside:

```
<div class="row">
  <TrainerCards v-for="trainer in orderBy(filterBy(trainers, searchText), sortAttribute, sortAscending)" :key="trainer.id" :trainer="trainer"/>
</div>


<template>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="card card-profile">
      <div class="card-img-top">
          <router-link v-bind:to="'/trainers/' + trainer.id">
            <img class="img" :src="(trainer.avatar)" />
          </router-link>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title">{{trainer.full_name}}</h4>
        <h6 class="card-category">{{trainer.location}}</h6>
        <div class="card-footer">
          <TrainerTags v-for="tag in trainer.tags" :key="tag.id" :tag="tag"/>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Oh wow I feel dumb. I'm ashamed about how long I was working on this. Thank you so much!